# permission denied in running script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos

I am running a script but there is an unusual warning:
This is what happened in my console

```
#whoami
root
#ls -l test.sh
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 1894 Feb  2 01:58 test.sh*
#./test.sh
-bash: ./test.sh: Permission denied
```

Edit:
my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read pass port user ip file; do
  echo "startt------------------------------------" $ip
  ping $ip -c 4
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo $ip ok...
  else
    echo $ip failed...
  fi
  echo "finish------------------------------------" $ip
done <<____HERE
pass  22  root  1.1.1.1  test.txt
____HERE
```

any idea?
thank you

Comment: Depends on what test.sh does (does it `kill -9 1`, for example?  Or `sudo tomcat rm -rf /`?  But mostly, this question belongs on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) since it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: Agree with @PaulHicks .  The program seems to be executing and there is a permission error within the script

Comment: no really..this is simple script..nothing unusual is happening in script

Comment: You can actually have a star in the filename on most linux systems. Judging by your [tag:ls] output, the file appears to have a * in the name. So try running it with `./"test.sh*"`

Comment: no...the name is test.sh

Comment: I'm guessing ls is aliased to ls -F

Comment: Sorry for downvoting, I'm trying to figure out how to remove my downvote.. it seems I can only upvote or downvote.. I'll undo it once I figure out how

Comment: That makes sense too, can you post the script? @PaulHicks, just press downvote again.

Comment: It is not a good idea using root on a day to day tasks

Comment: @PaulHicks - I gave him an upvote on your behalf

Comment: Hey, please no sympathy upvotes!  I've removed the downvote thanks to @BroSlow.

Comment: What happens when you use `bash -x test.sh` (to get console output of each line as it's executed)

Comment: @ Paul Hicks no problem and script works...I can see the output

Comment: but what is the problem??? any idea guys?

Comment: Make sure you're not trying to run the script from a filesystem that has the "noexec" option.

Comment: pardon, how can I do that?

Comment: If `/bin/bash` isn't executable, you'll get this error. What's `ls -l /bin/bash`?

Comment: I checked it..it seems no problem: -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 938832 Jul 18  2013 /bin/bash

Comment: try such command: "setenforce 0" and then try to run this script

Comment: @user2699113 no result :(

Comment: @user2699113 thankyou..let me complete you

Comment: @MortezaLSC if I helped you please upvote my post :)

Comment: as I said, no result..but may works after restarting the system...How can I upvote in comments dear friend? you should put your answer in answer part :D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am running the script in /tmp directory
as you see the result of ls is:

```
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 1894 Feb  2 01:58 test.sh*
```

there is `.` after permissions which indicates that an SELinux security context applies to that file. so I copied test.sh in a directory else...

the problem was solved

```
ls -l /
drwxrwxrwt.   8 root root  1024 Feb  2 07:44 tmp/
```

I was in a directory where it might be a bad idea for executables to reside

These may work as well:

```
setenforce 0 | reboot
```

OR

```
echo 0 > /selinux/enforce | reboot
```

OR:

```
putting SELINUX=disabled in /etc/selinux/config and reboot (making sure to comment out anything in that file enabling selinux)
```

SELINUX status: `sestatus`